# Извлечение картинок из pdf в linux

Tags: linux, pdf, sh

Как можно извлечь картинки из pdf файла в shell в linux?

Comment: ассоциация: https://askubuntu.com/q/150100/737131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать `pdfimages`:

```
pdfimages -all имя_файла.pdf ./префикс
```

`pdfimages` является частью пакета `poppler-utils`, который, вероятно, придётся установить

---

Вместо `./префикс` можно поставить любой `путь/до/папки/префикс`. Например, команда

```
pdfimages -all имя_файла.pdf /tmp/image
```

извлечёт картинки в файлы `/tmp/image-000.jpg`, `/tmp/image-001.jpg` и т.д.

---

Посмотреть список всех картинок в pdf файле можно так:

```
pdfimages -list имя_файла.pdf
```

Comment: Может стоит добавить в каком пакете содержится бинарник? Потому что например в 16-й убунте `aptitude search pdfimages` ничего не выдаёт, а `apt-file search pdfimages` - очень даже да.

Comment: @donRumata, да, отличное предложение, добавил